# How does AirBnb embed photos and videos on their experiences?

Tags: html, web, html5-video

[This experience for example](https://www.airbnb.com.au/experiences/66873?source=pdpother&currentTab=experience_tab&searchId=e6972458-922a-405d-bfe2-4d20090792a5&sectionId=b8472916-bbe0-4a86-a3c2-cdabda1c21fb) contains a video and a few photos. I tried using developer tools to find the video/images but was unable to find where they are embedded.

How does AirBnb embed these images and video?
I am asking as I want to add similar functionality on a personal website.

Comment: You can find the video with `document.querySelectorAll('video')`. Its probably some slider library in js with videos and images.

Comment: Adding on to @RolandStarke, they are simply using `video` tags for the videos, and a div with a background image for the "images". https://c.flm.pw/2019-01/7Z4KP.png

Comment: @AustenHolland Thank you!